# Haskell - How can I use pure functions inside IO functions?

Tags: haskell, io, referential-transparency

How can I use pure functions inside IO functions? :-/

For example: I'm reading a file (IO function) and I want to parse its context, a string, by using a pure function with referential transparency.

It seems such worlds, pure functions and IO functions, are separated. How can I possibly bridge them?

Comment: what tutorials did you read - every introduction to IO in haskell covers your question. The solution is to create the IO Monad.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. Look bellow:

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way is to use `fmap`, which has the following type:

```
fmap :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`IO` implements `Functor`, which means that we can specialize the above type by substituting `IO` for `f` to get:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

In other words, we take some function that converts `a`s to `b`s, and use that to change the result of an `IO` action.  For example:

```
getLine :: IO String

>>> getLine
Test<Enter>
Test
>>> fmap (map toUpper) getLine
Test<Enter>
TEST
```

What just happened there?  Well, `map toUpper` has type:

```
map toUpper :: String -> String
```

It takes a `String` as an argument, and returns a `String` as a result.  Specifically, it uppercases the entire string.

Now, let's look at the type of `fmap (map toUpper)`:

```
fmap (map toUpper) :: IO String -> IO String
```

We've upgraded our function to work on `IO` values.  It transforms the result of an `IO` action to return an upper-cased string.

We can also implement this using `do` notation, to:

```
getUpperCase :: IO String
getUpperCase = do
    str <- getLine
    return (map toUpper str)

>>> getUpperCase
Test<Enter>
TEST
```

It turns out that every monad has the following property:

```
fmap f m = do
    x <- m
    return (f x)
```

In other words, if any type implements `Monad`, then it should always be able to implement `Functor`, too, using the above definition.  In fact, we can always use the `liftM` as the default implementation of `fmap`:

```
liftM :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
liftM f m = do
    x <- m
    return (f x)
```

`liftM` is identical to `fmap`, except specialized to monads, which are not as general as functors.

So if you want to transform the result of an `IO` action, you can either use:

- `fmap`,
- `liftM`, or
- `do` notation

It's really up to you which one you prefer.  I personally recommend `fmap`.

Comment: Doesn't this explain how to extract the result of an IO action, rather than how to call a pure function *from* an IO action?

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider liftM function from Control.Monad.
A little example to help you (run it into ghci as you are under the IO Monad)

```
$ import Control.Monad -- to emerge liftM
$ import Data.Char     -- to emerge toUpper
$ :t map to Upper -- A pure function
map toUpper :: [Char] -> [Char]
$ :t liftM 
liftM :: Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r
$ liftM (map toUpper) getLine
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual answer is as follows:

```
main = do
  val <- return (purefunc ...arguments...)
  ...more..actions...
```

`return` wraps it in the appropriate monad so that `do` can assign it to **`val`**.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Horsman helped me. He said:

"Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but that sounds pretty simple?
do {x <- ioFunc; return (pureFunc x)}"

And then I solved my problem:

```
import System.IO  
import Data.List

getFirstPart line Nothing = line
getFirstPart line (Just index) = fst $ splitAt index line 

eliminateComment line = 
 getFirstPart line $ elemIndex ';' line

eliminateCarriageReturn line =
 getFirstPart line $ elemIndex '\r' line

eliminateEntersAndComments :: String -> String  
eliminateEntersAndComments text =
 concat $ map mapFunction $ lines text
 where
  mapFunction = (++ " ") . eliminateCarriageReturn . eliminateComment

main = do {
 contents <- readFile "../DWR-operators.txt"; 
 return (eliminateEntersAndComments contents)
}
```