# How to use pure functions recursively in types with IOMonad instances?

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I get the error:

```
Main.hs:38:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘WD ()’ with ‘()’
...
    • In the expression:
        setScrollHPos height >> scrollUntilEnd0 height <$> getHeight
```

where:

```
setScrollHPos :: Integer -> WD ()
scrollUntilEnd0 :: Integer -> Integer -> WD ()
scrollUntilEnd0 lastHeight height
  | lastHeight < height = setScrollHPos height >> scrollUntilEnd0
```

and `WD` has an `IOMonad` instance.

I am trying to use pure functions over values of I/O monads so, I tried the solution from the Stack Overflow question [Haskell - How can I use pure functions inside IO functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916721/haskell-how-can-i-use-pure-functions-inside-io-functions), but I am still unable to do it recursively.

##### Dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- http-client
- http-client-tls
- bytestring
- webdriver
```

##### Code:

````hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Module (main) where

import Test.WebDriver
import qualified Test.WebDriver.JSON as JSON
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

firefoxConfig :: WDConfig
firefoxConfig = hilf $ useBrowser firefox defaultConfig
  where
    hilf m = m { wdHTTPRetryCount = 100 }

main :: IO ()
main = runSession firefoxConfig $
  openPage "https://duckduckgo.com" >>
  
  scrollUntilEnd >>
  liftIO getLine >>

  closeSession
  where
    getHeight :: WD Integer
    getHeight = executeJS [] "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
    setScrollHPos :: Integer -> WD ()
    setScrollHPos height = JSON.ignoreReturn $ executeJS [JSArg height]
      "(function(h) { window.scrollTo(0, h); })"

    scrollUntilEnd0 :: Integer -> Integer -> WD ()
    scrollUntilEnd0 lastHeight height
      | lastHeight < height = setScrollHPos height >> scrollUntilEnd0 height <$> getHeight
      | otherwise            = pure ()
    
    scrollUntilEnd :: WD ()
    scrollUntilEnd = scrollUntilEnd0 0 <$> getHeight```
````

##### Error out:

```
Main.hs:34:31: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘WD ()’ with ‘()’
      Expected type: WD ()
        Actual type: WD (WD ())
    • In the expression:
        setScrollHPos height >> scrollUntilEnd0 height <$> getHeight
      In an equation for ‘scrollUntilEnd0’:
          scrollUntilEnd0 lastHeight height
            | lastHeight < height
            = setScrollHPos height >> scrollUntilEnd0 height <$> getHeight
            | otherwise = pure ()
      In an equation for ‘someFunc’:
          someFunc
            = runSession firefoxConfig
                $ openPage "https://duckduckgo.com" >> scrollUntilEnd
                    >> liftIO getLine
                    >> closeSession
            where
                getHeight :: WD Integer
                getHeight
                  = executeJS [] "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
                setScrollHPos :: Integer -> WD ()
                setScrollHPos height
                  = JSON.ignoreReturn
                      $ executeJS
                          [JSArg height] "(function(h) { window.scrollTo(0, h);
                ....
   |
34 |       | lastHeight < height = setScrollHPos height >> scrollUntilEnd0 heig
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Main.hs:38:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘WD ()’ with ‘()’
      Expected type: WD ()
        Actual type: WD (WD ())
    • In the expression: scrollUntilEnd0 0 <$> getHeight
      In an equation for ‘scrollUntilEnd’:
          scrollUntilEnd = scrollUntilEnd0 0 <$> getHeight
      In an equation for ‘someFunc’:
          someFunc
            = runSession firefoxConfig
                $ openPage "https://duckduckgo.com" >> scrollUntilEnd
                    >> liftIO getLine
                    >> closeSession
            where
                getHeight :: WD Integer
                getHeight
                  = executeJS [] "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
                setScrollHPos :: Integer -> WD ()
                setScrollHPos height
                  = JSON.ignoreReturn
                      $ executeJS
                          [JSArg height] "(function(h) { window.scrollTo(0, h);
                ....
   |
38 |     scrollUntilEnd = scrollUntilEnd0 0 <$> getHeight
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<$>` lets you pass a monadic input to a function with a non-monadic output. In your case, you want to pass a monadic input to a function with a monadic output, so you need [`=<<`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--60--60-) instead. For precedence reasons, you also now need parentheses, so do `setScrollHPos height >> (scrollUntilEnd0 height =<< getHeight)`.

Comment: @Delfin Not always, and I don't think you can in that particular snippet.

Comment: Could you pass me their entry in the Haskell Base library documentation pages.

Comment: @Delfin For `=<<`? I edited a link into my answer. For `$`? Here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-

Comment: and it don't let me use "$" in this case

Comment: So why did you comment that you could?

Comment: Yes, for `=<<`.

Comment: It was before try, and I tought it was valid.

Comment: As a style thing, I would avoid mixing "directions" of information flow. So, in this case, that means `setScrollHPos height >> getHeight >>= scrollUntilEnd0 height`. Minor bonus: no extra parentheses needed. The primary time I find `=<<` useful is when the other operator I'm trying to mix it with is `.`, which also has right-to-left information flow.